# C# generic type inference on delegate types

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

Does anyone know why C# is unable to infer the generic type arguments in this example?

```
var i = "1 2 3 dogs 4 5".Split(' ').SelectWhere(int.TryParse);
```

Where:

```
public delegate bool TryConverter<TIn, TOut>(TIn input, out TOut output);

public static IEnumerable<TOut> SelectWhere<TIn, TOut>(this IEnumerable<TIn> source, TryConverter<TIn, TOut> converter)
{
    foreach (TIn input in source)
    {
        if (converter(input, out TOut output))
            yield return output;
    }
}
```

I have encountered difficulties with type inference and custom delegate types in the past (but, AFAIK, because of the out parameter I'm unable to use my typical fallback to something like `Func<TIn, TOut, bool>` in this case).

This is obviously not a show-stopper—I can simply specify the type parameters or even do something like `new TryConverter<string, int>(int.TryParse)`. I'm more curious as to why C# can't/won't infer in situations like these.

Comment: Related? [Why is C# unable to infer the generic type argument type from a non-generic static method's signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20649168/1364007)

Comment: See first answer in marked duplicate. Type inference won't work from bare method group names. The parameter driving inference needs to be of a specific type, or be an anonymous method. If you were to cast the method group name to a delegate type, inference would work (as far as why the language is like this, I can't say authoritatively, but I expect it's because type inference is already involved in converting a method group to a delegate type, and asking the compiler to recursively infer types was impractical or otherwise undesirable)