# How can I get this method to infer type argument from usage?

Tags: c#, type-inference, type-parameter

I would like to get `TryGet` method to infer the type argument, just as it is possible for `TrySet`:

```
private void Test()
{
    TryGet<int>(RefProperty, s => s.GetInt); // works fine

    TryGet(RefProperty, s => s.GetInt); // CS0411 here

    TrySet(RefProperty, s => s.SetInt, 1234);
}

private T TryGet<T>(int property, Expression<Func<Material, Func<int, T>>> expression)
{
    return Material.HasProperty(property) ? expression.Compile()(Material)(property) : default;
}

private void TrySet<T>(int property, Expression<Func<Material, Action<int, T>>> expression, T value)
{
    if (Material.HasProperty(property))
    {
        expression.Compile()(Material)(property, value);
    }
}
```

Here are the signatures of `GetInt` and `SetInt` in `Material`:

```
int GetInt(int);

int GetInt(string);

void SetInt(int, int);

void SetInt(string, int);
```

Is this possible somehow or am I asking the compiler too much?

Comment: You might want to have a read at this question, it is pretty similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649168/why-is-c-sharp-unable-to-infer-the-generic-type-argument-type-from-a-non-generic

Comment: Albeit it doesn't solve my problem, that's an interesting read nonetheless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `TryGet` inherently returns a value, it makes sense to choose the value to return:

```
private void Test()
{
    TryGet(RefProperty, s => s.GetInt, 42);
}

private T TryGet<T>(int property, Expression<Func<Material, Func<int, T>>> expression, T defaultValue)
{
    return Material.HasProperty(property) ? expression.Compile()(Material)(property) : defaultValue;
}
```

Problem solved.